# Display message when the vector is empty

Tags: c++, vector

I would like to know how to display a message when a vector is empty. I know what is required but I don't know how to must be structured.

```
void displaypoints(const vector<int>& vec) {

    cout << "[";
    for (const auto& i : vec) {
        cout << i << ' ';
    }
    cout << "]" << endl;

};

int main() {

vector <int> myvec {};
vector <int> newvec {1,2,3,4,5};
cout << "myvec";
displaypoints(myvec);
cout << "newvec";
displaypoints(newvec);



if (newvec.at(0) == 1) {
    auto iq = find(newvec.begin(), newvec.end(), 1);
    if (iq != newvec.end()) {
        newvec.erase(iq);
    }



if (newvec.begin(), newvec.end(), 2) {

    auto ik = find(newvec.begin(), newvec.end(), 2);
    if (ik!= newvec.end()) {
    myvec.push_back(*ik);
    newvec.erase(ik);

}  

else if (newvec.begin(), newvec.end(), 3) {

    auto ik = find(newvec.begin(), newvec.end(), 3);
    if (ik!= newvec.end()) {
    myvec.push_back(*ik);
    newvec.erase(ik);


    }
}
}
}

if (newvec.at(0) == 5) {
    auto ik = find(newvec.begin(), newvec.end(), 5);
    if (ik!= newvec.end()) {
    myvec.push_back(*ik);
    newvec.erase(ik);

    }




}

displaypoints(newvec);
displaypoints(myvec);


}
```

The code above looks for the number 1, erases it then moves 2 to the myvec vector. If there is no 2 then it moves 3 because of the position 0 I have added. There is also another if statement that moves 5 if it is placed at position 0. What I want is another if statement to print a message if there is nothing in the newvec vector.

Comment: Is the message supposed to come from the `displaypoints()` function, or is it supposed to print in `main`? Either way, it probably has to do with the structure of your code. Your else if block is bad.

Comment: supposed to be printed in the main

Comment: ...by the `displaypoints()` function as far as I can tell. Your main has no couts other than the vector names.

Comment: the display prints out the vectors , I just haven't added in the functions

Comment: ive added the function

Comment: And you realize that you don't move the value 4, right?

Comment: Yes I don't move the value 4

Comment: Not to worry I have mended the issue it works fine now

Comment: The statement `if (newvec.begin(), newvec.end(), 3)` is always true. The expression `(a,b,c)` will evaluate to `c`.

Comment: @maany It is unclear what you are trying to achieve. For example this if statement if (newvec.begin(), newvec.end(), 2) { does not even compile. At first describe the task using the human language.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void
display_points(const std::vector<int>& v)
{
  if (v.empty()) {
    std::cout << "Empty vector.\n";
  } else {
    std::cout << "[ ";
    for (const auto& i : v) {
      std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << "]\n";
  }
}

int
main()
{
  std::vector<int> myvec;
  std::vector<int> newvec{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

  std::cout << "myvec: ";
  display_points(myvec);
  std::cout << "newvec:";
  display_points(newvec);

  int i = 1;
  while (newvec.size() > 0) {
    auto it = std::find(newvec.begin(), newvec.end(), i);
    if (it != newvec.end()) {
      myvec.push_back(*it);
      newvec.erase(it);
    }
    ++i;
  }

  std::cout << "myvec: ";
  display_points(myvec);
  std::cout << "newvec:";
  display_points(newvec);
}
```

Comment: ive already tried that it doesn't work for some reason, I think it may have something to do with the way ive structured it

Answer (score 0):

```
void displaypoints(vector<int> & vec){
    if(vec.empty()){
        cout<<"Vector Empty \n";
    }
    else {
        //do your operations
    }
}
```

whatever Ide you are using try first clean build and then build all and run the code it will work.